# Python: concatenating a given number of loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have this part of a code:

```
N = 4
coa = []
for a in range(N):
    for b in range(N):
        for c in range(N):
            for d in range (N):
                coa.append(a,b,c,d)
```

Basically, I need to concatenate as many for-loop as the number `N`. Therefore, if `N` had been equal to `6`, I would have had to add other two for-loops with letters `e` and `f` and to add the same letters inside`coa.append()`. Is there a possibility to do that automatically, meaning that by varying the integer value of N, all that is done without typing it?

Comment: Use `itertools.product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` and `repeat()`:

Here is an example:

```
In [3]: from itertools import product, repeat

In [5]: 

In [5]: list(product(*repeat(range(3), 3)))
Out[5]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 2),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 2, 0),
 (0, 2, 1),
 (0, 2, 2),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 2),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 0),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (2, 0, 0),
 (2, 0, 1),
 (2, 0, 2),
 (2, 1, 0),
 (2, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 2, 0),
 (2, 2, 1),
 (2, 2, 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry if my question was a diplicate of a precedent one. Anyway, I haven't been able to understand the previous answer, whereas this one is perfect!!!